# Creating an Arithmetic Task Runner

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been tasked to create an Arithmetic Task Runner as part of my assignment.

Up until today I've never used NodeJS or even the terminal to execute a script.

I have been working on this for the past 5 hours and still no luck. I have avoided coming here and asking as I'd like to figure it out for myself, however, I have succumbed to desperately needing help.

This is the code I have so far:

```
class ArithmeticTaskRunner {
    static set taskCount(counter) {
        throw new('This is a readOnly accessor, the value is ${value}');
    }

    add(y) {
        this.y = y || 0
        console.log(y)
        }

         minus(x) {
            this.x = Math.abs(this.y) * -1;
            console.log(this.x);
        };

    multiply(z) {
        this.z = z * this.x;
        console.log(this.z)
    }

    execute(startValue) {
       this.startValue = startValue + this.y
       this.y = this.startValue
        console.log(this.startValue)
        this.startValue = this.minus
        console.log(this.startValue)
        this.startValue = this.multiply(this.startValue)
        console.log(this.startValue)
    }
}

tasks = [
    function() { minus()},
    function() { multiply(z)},  
    function() { add(x)},
    function() { execute(x)}    
]
```

This is nowhere near perfect, but it's 80%-90% near completion.

This is the task I have been given:

```
You should implement a class called ArithmeticTaskRunner with the following:
- An instance variable named tasks which is initialised to an empty array upon
creation.
- A method named addNegationTask which adds an anonymous function to the
tasks array. This anonymous function should take one argument, x, and return the
negation, -x.
- A method named addAdditionTask which takes a single argument y, and adds
an anonymous function to the tasks array. This anonymous function should take
one argument, x, and return the result x + y.
- A method named addMultiplicationTask which takes a single argument y,
and adds an anonymous function to the tasks array. This anonymous function
should take one argument, x, and return the result x * y.
- A read-only accessor named taskCount which returns the number of queued tasks.
- A method named execute, which takes a single argument named startValue.
If omitted, startValue defaults to zero. Starting at startValue, this method should iterate over the tasks array executing each function on the current value. It then returns the resulting number after all arithmetic operations have been executed.
```

I'd be grateful for any help I could get.

The issues I have are the following: The execute method (trying to make the `startValue`, after the addition, a negative), the multiplication method and the fact I cannot call the addition method twice without overriding the value. The examples of the program fully working have shown I should allow for a method to be called multiple times without overriding the previous value.

I know there's a rule where it's one question per issue, I concede that. But if anyone can help me out with any of the issues I will truly be grateful and I will compensate people for their efforts.

Thank you.

Edit - This is an example of both the expected inputs/outputs

```
> let taskRunner = new ArithmeticTaskRunner()
undefined
> taskRunner.addAdditionTask(2)
undefined
> taskRunner.addMultiplicationTask(4)
undefined
> taskRunner.addAdditionTask(10)
undefined
> taskRunner.execute(2)
26
> taskRunner.execute(-2)
10
```

Comment: I apologize in advance for the people who will object to doing your homework for you.  But it looks like you came apart even after the first instruction.  Your class should have an instance variable named tasks.  You put your "tasks" outside the class as a global.  You should have a constructor for ArithmeticTaskRunner and it should say `this.tasks = []`

Comment: You should have a method named `addNegationTask` that says something like `this.tasks.push( (x) => -x )`

Comment: @Wyck Thank you ever so much. I have added this piece of code `  constructor () {  this.tasks = []; }` Just beneath `taskCount`. And regarding the people who will object, what can I say? I don't blame them. But the issue is each week we use  different language/program. 2 weeks ago I had to use Pharo, last week Ruby, this week NodeJS, next week Clojure and then Haskell. We don't learn the language thoroughly or in depth.

Comment: @Wyck I just called the method `add` for ease of use when using terminal. But thank you once again!

Comment: The instructions say to create a series of methods called add???Task, where ??? is "negation", "addition", and so on.  Instructions say these functions must add functions to the taskArray.  The posted code doesn't include functions with the add???Task names, and it doesn't do anything to add any function to any array.  Why not?

Comment: @danh I changed negation to `minus`, addition to `add` and multiplication to `multiply` just for testing purpose and ease of calling. I shall change the name of the methods once I hopefully have the program working. That's all.

Comment: Renaming them is a good start (if I was the teacher, and I told you to name a function X, I'd expect you to name it X).  The instructions also indicate that those functions you're going to rename don't *perform* math, they add to an array an anonymous function that performs math.

Comment: @danh It was just for ease of use that's all. I shall ammend the names upon hopefully completion. I have looked into anonymous functions I have a slight idea of how they operate. So the methods don't perform the mathematical logic rather the array does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to provide the whole answer because this is an assignment for you, but here's some code that might help you out.  This starts with `5` then calls `doubleIt` and then calls `addOne` to arrive at `11`.

It does this by creating an array of functions, each one performs a simple task and returns the result of its input modified in some way.

Then it creates a function called `execute` that uses Array.reduce to call the first function in the array with a given initial value, then repeatedly calls each function in the array on the result.  Check the documentation for [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) if you're confused about how it works.

```js
doubleIt = x => x * 2;
addOne = x => x + 1;
tasks = [doubleIt, addOne];
execute = (initial) => tasks.reduce((x,fn) => fn(x), initial)
document.write(execute(5))
```

#### Hint #2

```js
class ArithmeticTaskRunner {
  constructor() {
    this.tasks = [];
  }
  
  addAdditionTask(arg) {
    this.tasks.push(x => x + arg);
  }
    
  addMultiplicationTask(arg) {
    this.tasks.push(x => x * arg);
  }
  
  execute(startValue) {
    return this.tasks.reduce((x, fn) => fn(x), startValue);
  }
}

let taskRunner = new ArithmeticTaskRunner()
taskRunner.addAdditionTask(2)
taskRunner.addMultiplicationTask(4)
taskRunner.addAdditionTask(10)
document.write(taskRunner.execute(2));
document.write(', ');
document.write(taskRunner.execute(-2));
```

Comment: Thank you for much for the help you have shown thus far, however, I believe this would be incorrect. I had edited my question and have added an example of what the input/output should be on the console. Hope this clarifies everything. But once again I am extremely grateful for your time and help.

Comment: Pretty sure I'm right on the money.  Why do you think this would be incorrect?  This was just an example of how to write your "execute" function, and this is a good example of what you need, I believe.

Comment: The reason I believe this isn't the correct way is due to the assignment saying each method should have a parameter where data can be passed through I believe. That's all.

Comment: This is my methods currently in action  `> let tr = new ArithmeticTaskRunner()
undefined
> tr.add(10)
10
undefined
> tr.minus()
-10
undefined
> tr.multiply(0.5)
-5` I get the correct outputs. It's just my execute method is wrong I know this for a fact as it needs to iterate through the `tasks` array and use the values inputted.

Comment: OK, I edited with more of the answer spelled out.  You should really be doing this part yourself though.  I think this is now "too much" of a hint.

Comment: I have apparently done it wrong. Someone was kind enough to tell me the methods do not actually do the mathematical operation(s) rather it's the array. I am so sorry for wasting your time and probably infuriating you as well. I genuinely appreciate the help I really do. I will be more than happy to compensate you for your efforts. Side note- we are using the terminal/command line. So to print it's `console.log`

Comment: I'm not infuriated.  I enjoy helping people.  I work for free.  Compensate me with an upvote and kind remark.

Comment: If there is ever a time where you need any assistance with iOS/Swift please I urge you to contact me. I would happily upvote you but I need at least 15 reputation in order to do so. Also would the following: `addNegationTask` be the following: `addNegationTask(arg) {  this.tasks.push(x => arg * -1); }`

Comment: Just `addNegationTask() { this.tasks.push(x => -x); }`.  Because negation doesn't require an argument. You can "accept" my answer too, even with low rep.

Comment: "compensate me with an upvote".  +1 from me, and a kind remark: "You're a smart and helpful chap, Wyck".  And free advice: reduce might be too tough for a newbie (maybe make it forEach with stack variable).

Comment: I disagree, that's like saying "sentences are hard, because of grammar.  We should just grunt individual words at each other."  And true, we begin as babies with individual words, but our parents speak to us in sentences.  But I appreciate the journey you are on, and it's good that you recognize already that reduce works like a forEach.

Comment: @danh Dude, I don't know why you're giving me a hard time. I apologise if I'm not the best at Node JS or JavaScript, I truly am. I understand you're trying to help me but what have I done to upset you?

Comment: @Wyck Just one small issue, I need to set the `startValue` to 0 is there is no `startValue` would this be `startValue || 0' right at the end of the  execute method? And also at least, let me buy you a cup of coffee? Edit: I added the || section and the issue is resolved.

Comment: @TheNewbie, what hard time? What upset? I pointed you to two ways that the posted code violated the assignment; things that require basic skills in order to be compliant. Then I upvoted this good answer, and suggested one aspect might be too tough for a beginner.

Comment: @danh OK fair enough, I apologise for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @TheNewbie, if you want a default value of 0 when you call `execute` without an argument then you can define the execute function with:  `execute(startvalue = 0) { /* blah blah blah */ }` as long as you are using es2015.  Then calling `taskRunner.execute()` will work as if you had called `taskRunner.execute(0)`

Comment: @TheNewbie please don't request that an answer be defaced for this or any purpose. Best for you to borrow the ideas from the 2nd hint, not the code. In other words **you** must amend your code, not Wyck.